# At what complexity do multiple trips outweigh a single query for an object graph?

Tags: database, performance

When issuing a query against a database, at what depth of an object graph does it actually become more performant to just use multiple trips instead of one huge query?

Comment: probably never as transporting data to the "processing" unit, especially data that will be filtered out, will most likely always be more expensive than filtering data locally and sending *less* data to client

Comment: That really depends, though.  Just one example: some DB platforms are very bad at dealing with hierarchies.

Comment: Is he asking about hierarchical data? I thought his Object graph is his application Entity model.

Comment: @srini.venigalla - In the context I am asking about, an object graph is hierarchical. A good quote from wiki on it: "Object-oriented applications contain complex webs of interrelated objects." Consider this as a complex object graph with depth 3: A harbor, containing a set of ships, which contain a set of crates, each with a set of contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational Databases (assuming you are asking about them) do not understand/view the Objects/Entities in the middleware. As such, they will not know at what depth your queries are originating from. They all run in a stateless declarative fashion.

Having said that, in general, several simple queries in the place of a large query does not seriously hurt the performance provided (1) the connections are reused via pooling (2) the connection open-close lifecycle is short.

A large query that gets a lot of data is also desirable provided the underlying database is well tuned and well indexed. It reduces the traffic, uses less connections and aids in concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unanswerable in the current form.

It depends on the nature of the complexity, on the database platforms (and version) in question, on the network connectivity, and so on.

The best way to approach this problem in my experience is

- Trust your instincts first
- Measure the result
- Change strategy if the performance is unacceptable
- Learn from the experience

Comment: Would a more specific environment help? ASP.NET MVC 3 for example with EF and a MySQL database. What I am really trying to get by "complexity" with regards to an object graph is the amount of relations included as joins.